# Android: Add text to status bar

Tags: android

I am working on JellyBean. I want to add some text to the status bar when my application starts. (This text is not related to notifications).
Is it possible to add plain text(without any notifications) to the status bar?
If yes, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so..

The statusbar is not a Java application, but a part of the Framework classes of the Android OS. 
The classes are compiled in DEX format and then ODEX-ed in compiletime and are not editable in runtime.

There is no way (to my knowladge) that you're able to add text except by using the notification subsystem.

Comment: Thank you Tancho for the information. Even I searched a lot but I could not find any solution. For the notification, the notification icon remains persistent in the status bar and the ticker text just flows away. So, can we make this ticker text in the notification make persistent as the icon?

Comment: I guess, theoretically, you could work on building a custom ROM and edit the status bar in the firmware. Or you could create as many icons with the text as you need, but this could end up being 100 for something simple like a battery % and so on. The only simple way in Java is to use Notifications. I've hit this barrier myself today and it's a bit annoying, especailly as twitter does it (but I'm assuming it is built into the ROM/Firmware to begin with).